# AWS SNS and Waiter functions for boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-sns

I am playing around with AWS trying to write an app that takes advantage of the Pub-Sub pattern using SNS/SQS through the boto3 library. I will provide code if needed, but I think my question is quite general.

I have read the documentation on waiters, but when I go to display the available waiters for SNS the list comes back empty. I also tried to get a list of available SQS waiters but that came back empty as well.

Are there conditions that exist that determine whether or not waiter functions are accessible? Is there a policy setting that needs to be in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing else to do as there are no waiters for SQS or SNS as you can see below:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 25 2018, 14:26:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import boto3
 >>> sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
 >>> sns = boto3.client('sns')
 >>> sqs.waiter_names
[]
 >>> sns.waiter_names
[]
```

And here are two GitHub issues for [SQS](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/863) and [SNS](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/312) where people are asking for waiters.

Comment: You have saved my sanity. I did not see anywhere that said that waiters do not exist for SNS/SQS so I figured I was doing something wrong.

Comment: always happy to help!